# Relation between directional derivatives and derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is it possible to say that the directional derivatives of a function f at a exists but f is not differentiable at a? If so, why? I cannot get the intuition about it. Could someone please elaborate on this point a little bit?

I am self studying mostly, so I need to discuss these trivial matters with someone :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, Care Bear's link gives an example.

An explanation as to the why:   Directional derivatives gives you the rate of change on any STRAIGHT LINE path.   (I.e., the limit along a straight line).  In order for a limit to exist in multiple dimensions,  it must be the same on *any* path,  not just straight line paths.    There's simple examples of functions that all the limits on straight lines are the same, but not on say, parabolas.